# How do I highlight the contours on all the images normally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I need to highlight the outline on all the images presented with OpenCV on Python

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried that code but it's doesn't work normally on second image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Input image and make it gray
image = cv2.imread("img2.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Blur
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Draw dots onto image
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.WaitKey(0)
```

It should work like this somehow

[image]

Comment: "normally"? Can you show us how?

Comment: @AKX, I added a photo to the question

Comment: Why did your code not work? What results did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the line `thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]`. Your first and third image worked because they have dark brown colour, which most likely did not satisfy the threshold value and got inversed to white by cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, compared to the second one which is light brown and most likely satisfied the threshold value thus got inversed to black. I suggest you try playing with the threshhold parameter to achieve your desired result. You can checkout the [trackbar documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dc8/tutorial_py_trackbar.html) for ease of changing the threshold.